# SKMaps continously crashing with SIGSEGV error in offline mode [Android]

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I am getting SIGSEGV error every time when I try to zoomin/zoomout map for 2-3 time in Offline Map. It even crashes if I try to move map for different places and it is getting very frustrating. I recently download the demo project provided by Skobbler even that app is also crashing. 
I have Samsung galaxy TAB with android 5.0(lolipop) on it.

```
04-11 18:58:43.220 12175-12569/com.skobbler.sdkdemo A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xbb7da5e0 passed to dlfree
04-11 18:58:43.220 12175-12569/com.skobbler.sdkdemo A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 12569 (kobbler.sdkdemo)
```

I think it is a known issue in SKMAPS. Does anyone has solution or workaround for this crash issue?

> ** I am not using online map, only Offline maps with prebundles maps provides by SKM

Comment: What version of SKMaps are you using?

Comment: @SmedleyDSlap version 3.0.1, tried in 3.0.2 as well, but getting same crash

Comment: Same problem here :(

Comment: Did you fixed this problem? :/

Comment: @David No, but I downgraded the library to version 2.5 and that is working fine for me.